# Show that $\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^3}\sin(nx)=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}\sin{(2n-1)x}.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So after solving another problem, I got the answer on the LHS below. The book says it's the RHS. However, both of them are correct but I want to know how to go from my answer to the books. Thus the problem I need help with is

> Show that $$\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq
>  1}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^3}\sin(nx)=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq
>  1}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}\sin{((2n-1)x)}.\tag 1$$

The original problem was to find the fourier series of the function $f(x)=x(\pi-|x|).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not hard to prove.$$\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq
 1}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^3}\sin(nx){=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq
 1\\n \text{ is odd}}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^3}\sin(nx)+\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq
 1\\n \text{ is even}}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^3}\sin(nx)\\=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq
 1\\n \text{ is odd}}\frac{1-(-1)}{n^3}\sin(nx)+\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq
 1\\n \text{ is even}}\frac{1-(1)}{n^3}\sin(nx)\\=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq
 1\\n \text{ is odd}}\frac{2}{n^3}\sin(nx)\\=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq
 1\\n=2k-1\\k\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^3}\sin(nx)\\=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^3}\sin\Big((2k-1)x\Big)}$$

Answer (score 3):

The coefficient $1^n-(-1)^n$ in the LHS is $0$ for even $n$ and $2$ for odd $n$.
Therefore the resulting coefficients:
$$
\frac4\pi\cdot\frac{1^n-(-1)^n}{n^3}=\begin{cases}
\frac8\pi\frac1{n^3},&n-\text{odd}\\
0,&n-\text{even}\\
\end{cases}
$$
are identical with these in RHS, where the change of the index $n\mapsto 2n-1$ was performed to ensure summation over odd numbers.

Comment: Should it not be $\frac{8}{\pi}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}?$

Comment: Of course it is as every *odd* positive number can be written as $2k-1$ with $k$ being a positive integer number with arbitrary parity. Important is to use the same representation both in the prefactor and in the argument of sine.